# Program received signal: “0”: If this is caused by memory leaks why do I not receive memory warnings?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks

After a few minutes of intense use my app quits with "Program received signal:  “0”." As far as I've been able to determine this signal is caused by excessive memory usage. What puzzles me is that I often don't get any memory warnings at all prior to the app crashing. If I'm using too much memory shouldn't the OS emit a memory warning before booting me?

The only alternative that I can think of is that I'm requesting such a huge single block of memory that the OS just balks and boots me immediately, but that doesn't seem to be the case either: the crash often occurs in situations where there's no massive allocations of memory.

What am I not understanding about how memory warnings work or about signal 0?

P.S. - The app is an iPad only app compiled with the 4.3 SDK and targeting iOS 3.2 and above.

Comment: If you're (mis)handling RAW images, for instance, GPU memory can fill up and kill the app with signal 0 and no memory warnings issued. THe best thing is you can't see that memory being allocated in Allocations Instruments. I assume there are other cases where memory warnings are not issued.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I never thought of the GPU memory filling up as a possible cause of memory crashes. I ended up making various changes to the app and lowering the amount of images I was using which resolved the crash, so I'm not sure what ultimately was causing it but I'll keep your tip in mind for future memory problems.